# Setting Python KafkaProducer sasl mechanism property

Tags: python, ssl, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-security

The sasl mechanism we are using is `SCRAM-SHA-256` but the kafka producer will only accept `sasl_mechanism` as `PLAIN`, `GSSAPI`, `OAUTHBEARER`

The following config will give the error

```
sasl_mechanism must be in PLAIN, GSSAPI, OAUTHBEARER
```

config

```
    ssl_produce = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='brokerCName:9093',
                     security_protocol='SASL_SSL',
                     ssl_cafile='pemfilename.pem',
                     sasl_mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-256',
                     sasl_plain_username='password',
                     sasl_plain_password='secret')
```

I need to know how can I specify the correct sasl mechanism.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated answer for kafka-python v2.0.0+**

Since [2.0.0](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/pull/1918), kafka-python supports both `SCRAM-SHA-256` and `SCRAM-SHA-512`.

---

**Previous answer for older versions of `kafka-python`**

As far as I understand, you are using [`kafka-python`](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/) client. From the [source code](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/_modules/kafka/conn.html), I can see that `sasl_mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-256'` is not a valid option:

```
    """
    ...
    sasl_mechanism (str): Authentication mechanism when security_protocol
        is configured for SASL_PLAINTEXT or SASL_SSL. Valid values are:
        PLAIN, GSSAPI, OAUTHBEARER.
    ...
    """

    if self.config['security_protocol'] in ('SASL_PLAINTEXT', 'SASL_SSL'):
        assert self.config['sasl_mechanism'] in self.SASL_MECHANISMS, (
            'sasl_mechanism must be in ' + ', '.join(self.SASL_MECHANISMS))
```

One quick workaround is to use [`confluent-kafka`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) client that supports  `sasl_mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-256'`:

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer 

# See https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md
conf = {
    'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',
    'security.protocol': 'SASL_SSL',
    'sasl.mechanisms': 'SCRAM-SHA-256',
    'sasl.username': 'yourUsername',
    'sasl.password': 'yourPassword', 
    # any other config you like ..
}

p = Producer(**conf)
 
# Rest of your code goes here..
```

Answer (score 5):

[`kafka-python`](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/blob/2.0.0/kafka/producer/kafka.py#L270) supports both `SCRAM-SHA-256` and `SCRAM-SHA-512` in version [2.0.0](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/releases/tag/2.0.0).